# Free hosting github in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, web, github-pages

I've created a website in React.js and Node.js.
I'd like to launch it with a free hosting github.
I've done publishing my website with gh-pages.
However, it doesn't show anything.
I found a reason because my App.js has just Route like below.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/test" element={<Main/>}/>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/me" element={<Me/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

How can I show my Home page?
Should I put all codes in the app.js?

Comment: In App.js, I've changed BrowserRouter to HashRouter.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages only works with static pages, so you need to add react in your HTML. See https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html